# jtable won't update while the program is running

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jtable

**okay i already posted this but i delete it because no one is answering for 24 hours already**

i don't really know what to do anymore. i have so many tables in my system and they all have the same codes but this is the only on that doesn't work. my problem is that every time i add candidate/data to the jtable, it won't appear. it will only appear if i terminate the program then run it again. here is my codes:

**This is the class that contains storing to file and jtable methods**

```
    public class DatabaseForCandidates {
        String pres; 
        int resPres;
        static Vector rowsPres;
        static String [] columnPres={"PRESIDENTIAL CANDIDATES", "CURRENT NUMBER OF VOTES", ""};
        static File filePres;
        static FileWriter fileWrite;
        static FileReader fileRead;
        static Scanner read;

        public DatabaseForCandidates() {
            filePres=new File("President.txt");
            fileWrite=null;
            fileRead=null;
            read=null;
        }
        public void setColumns(){
            PresidentTable.tblModel=new DefaultTableModel();
            PresidentTable.tblModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnPres);
            PresidentTable.tblNatPresident=new JTable(PresidentTable.tblModel);
        }

    public void storePresidentRecords(){
            try {
                fileWrite=new FileWriter(filePres,true);
                getDataPres();  
                storeToTable();

                //storing to a file
                fileWrite.write("**"+pres+"**"); fileWrite.write(resPres+"**");
            fileWrite.write("\r\n");

            fileWrite.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Candidate is now nominated for President");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void getDataPres(){
        String linePres="";
        try {
            fileRead=new FileReader(Database.fileNew);
            read=new Scanner(fileRead);

            while(read.hasNext()){
                linePres+=read.nextLine()+"\n";
            }
            read.close();

            String [] infoPres=linePres.split("/");

            pres=infoPres[4]+" "+infoPres[3];
            resPres=0;
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public void storeToTable(){
        rowsPres=new Vector();
        rowsPres.add(pres); rowsPres.add(resPres);
        PresidentTable.tblModel.addRow(rowsPres);
    }

    public void retrievePresidentRecords(){
        String holdStr="";
        try {
            fileRead=new FileReader(filePres);
            read=new Scanner(fileRead);

            while(read.hasNext()){
                holdStr+=read.nextLine()+"\n";
            }
            read.close();

            StringTokenizer strToken=new StringTokenizer(holdStr, "**");

            while(strToken.hasMoreElements()){
                rowsPres=new Vector();
                for(int i=0; i<columnPres.length; i++){
                    rowsPres.add(strToken.nextElement());
                }
                PresidentTable.tblModel.addRow(rowsPres);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**this is the class of jtable**

```
public class PresidentTable extends JPanel{
    static JTable tblNatPresident;
    static DefaultTableModel tblModel;
    DatabaseForCandidates data;

    PresidentTable(){
        setName("panelNatPres");

        data=new DatabaseForCandidates();

        data.setColumns();
        data.retrievePresidentRecords();

        PresidentTable.tblNatPresident=new JTable(PresidentTable.tblModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(PresidentTable.tblNatPresident));
    }
}
```

**this is the listener of the button if you will add candidate or not**

```
if(e.getSource().equals(PresidentPanel.btnPresAdd)){
            DatabaseForCandidates data=new DatabaseForCandidates();
            boolean found=false;
            try {
                String add=PresidentPanel.txtVNum.getText();
                String vnum=null;
                for (int row=0; (row<ViewTablePanel.tblModel.getRowCount()) && (!found);row++) {
                    vnum=ViewTablePanel.tblModel.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
                    if(vnum.equals(add)){
                        found=true;
                        data.storePresidentRecords();
                    }
                }
                if(!found){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, add+" is not found.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {}
        }
```

just ask me if you don't understand my code and if you have any clarification. please help thank you so much  :)

Comment: You'll have more success if you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read through that link please), that is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. Posting a bunch of excerpts is hard to debug with eyes. Posting one excerpt that people can copy/paste in their development environment will be easier. Help those that are trying to help you.

Comment: `i have so many tables in my system and they all have the same codes but this is the only on that doesn't work` - so then you need to do some debugging to see what is different. We can't look at all your code to see what you are doing differently. Also, using static variables is the sign of a poorly designed application. Create a panel for your JTable then define all the variables and methods that you need to manage the table within that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you posting the whole code it's hard to debug. However a few things that could be wrong come to mind:

1. **You don't notify the JTable that the data has changed by calling:** `.fireTableDataChanged()`
2. **You don't update the frame with:** `.repaint();` **and** `.revalidate();`
3. **You update your file, but do not read the file updates or otherwise update the change to your JTable.**

Comment: i thought updating the table is like updating the model and as far as i what i read and understand it's this line of code `PresidentTable.tblModel.addRow(rowsPres);`. and also this is also the code on my other tables it's just this is the only one that doesn't work. but yes i will try your suggestion thank you so much :)

Comment: @bruh No problem, but as i said, if you upload your whole project to GitHub or something similar and post the link it will be much easier for me to debug. Also let me know if it worked!

Comment: there could be a few instances of PresidentTable.tblModel.addRow(rowsPres);, which one is updated, nothing else without an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variables

Comment: @mKorbel Note that 1) `[mcve]` in a comment expands to [mcve] (automatically). 2) That is a great suggestion of yours. 3) I am very drunk. 4) Point (3) in no way impacts on points (1) or (2) - I just thought I'd mention it, for the hell of it. ;)

Comment: 1. The `.fireTableDataChanged() method (or more specific method) is already being called since he is using DefaultTableModel, a model that automatically makes these appropriate calls when rows are added or removed, or data is changed. 2. repaint and revalidate is only required if components are added to a layout-manager using component, not when changing the data within a TableModel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: hoping that you made a smooth recovery of function.